# Type mismatch error when assigning date to variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through expiration dates in column "G" and compare them with today's date. The code loops through 363 times whenever I run it but then it stops at `ExpirationDate = Cells(x, "G").Value` and gives me a type mismatch error.

All the cells in column "G" are marked as dates and so is ExpirationDate. There is no difference that I can see between the row that the code always stops at and the rows prior which successfully passed through the code.

```
    For x = 13 To numrows
        reminderrows = Worksheets("Reminders").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        expiredrows = Worksheets("Expired").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Worksheets("Training Log Test").Activate

        ExpirationDate = Cells(x, "G").Value

        If ExpirationDate > today And ExpirationDate <= ninetydays Then
            Rows(x).Copy
            Worksheets("Reminders").Activate
            Worksheets("Reminders").Cells(reminderrows + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

        ElseIf today >= ExpirationDate Then
            Rows(x).Copy
            Worksheets("Expired").Activate
            Worksheets("Expired").Cells(expiredrows + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Else
        End If
    Next       
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the actual value in the cell when the error raises? Have you tried `ExpirationDate = CDate(Cells(x, "G").Value)`?

Comment: Please show your declared variables.  Are you using serial date or just date?  What is the number of rows you're working?

Comment: *marked as dates* doesn't mean *is* a date. see this often with text-formatted-as-date, or dates from locales that aren't the system locale, etc.

Comment: You can check if the value in the Cell is a date with [IsDate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isdate-function?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008951)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) function. This will help you troubleshoot.

Comment: The actual value in the cell is 10/2/2019

Comment: Does `Debug.Print TypeName(ExpirationDate)` output `Date` or `String`? Is it declared anywhere? With an explicit type? If so then note that cell values should be read into a `Variant`, lest you get a *type mismatch* error if you try to read a worksheet error value (e.g. `#REF!`) into a `Date`, `String`, or any other type.

Answer (score 0):

Please try replacing the following line:

```
 ExpirationDate = Cells(x, "G").Value
```

with this:

```
ExpirationDate = Cells(x,7).Value
```